# Cannot deserialize object from a JSON string (but only to Hash)?

Tags: ruby, json, deserialization

I wrote the [dictation](https://github.com/thyrlian/dictation) gem on my Mac, and deserialization works fine.  When I installed it on another Mac it would not work because it "fails" to deserialize object, because it can only deserialize to a Hash.

- Private Mac Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3-p0,   json v1.8.0
- Another Mac Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3-p448, json v1.8.0

I also tried different Ruby versions and Gem versions on both, but none of them works, only the initial one where I first wrote it.

When I try this code in the working environment:

```
require 'json'

class Word
  attr_accessor :value, :translation

  def initialize(value, translation)
    @value = value
    @translation = translation
  end

  def to_json(*args)
    {
      'json_class' => self.class.name,
      'data'       => [ @value, @translation ]
    }.to_json(*args)
  end

  class << self
    def json_create(object)
      new(*object['data'])
    end
  end
end

str = '{"json_class":"Word","data":["Morgen","Tomorrow"]}'
p JSON.parse(str)
```

It prints a Word object, which is expected:

```
#<Word:0x007fcce22c9c58 @translation="Tomorrow", @value="Morgen">
```

With the other environment, it always prints a Hash:

```
{"json_class"=>"Word", "data"=>["Morgen", "Tomorrow"]}
```

I also tried to pass `:object_class key`, it throws another exception:

```
p JSON.parse(str, :object_class => Word)
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
```

I could not figure out the `require 'json'` version during runtime using:

```
puts Gem.loaded_specs['json'].version
```

because `Gem.loaded_specs.keys` doesn't contain it.

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replied from the author of JSON lib - on newer version, due to security reason, to deserialize custom object, either you can:

```
JSON.parse(str, :create_additions => true)
```

or you can:

```
JSON.load(str)
```

So, I overlooked the [JSON#load](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-load) part in ruby-doc:

```
load(source, proc = nil, options = {})
```

> Load a ruby data structure from a JSON source and return it. A source
>   can either be a string-like object, an IO-like object, or an object
>   responding to the read method. If proc was given, it will be called
>   with any nested Ruby object as an argument recursively in depth first
>   order. To modify the default options pass in the optional options
>   argument as well.
>
> BEWARE: This method is meant to serialise data from trusted user
>   input, like from your own database server or clients under your
>   control, it could be dangerous to allow untrusted users to pass JSON
>   sources into it. The default options for the parser can be changed via
>   the ::load_default_options method.
>
> This method is part of the implementation of the load/dump interface
>   of Marshal and YAML.

Answer (score 0):

Deserializing directly into a rich object (especially if your JSON comes from an unknown source) can be a pretty serious attack vector (recent Rails vulnerabilities are related to that).

I would guess that this ability was disabled between Ruby versions, or, at least changed to a whitelist-based approach. I wasn't able to find any links to support this claim though, so I might be wrong.

Anyway, you might find it simpler and more compatible to initialize your class from the deserialized hash instead:

```
class Word
  def self.from_json(json)
    args = JSON.parse(json)["data"];
    new(*args)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Renato.  Yes, this can indeed solve the problem of deserialization.  But the question is why the json_create used by built-in JSON#parse doesn't work.  If so, why doesn't the author remove that?  And could you please also share any link regarding the attack risk problem, that would be interesting to know the underneath problem.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another workaround, because my code is not used in web communication, vulnerability is not a problem here.

Before I was doing:

```
JSON.parse(str)
```

Now just need to add few lines:

```
obj = JSON.parse(str)
if obj.is_a?(Hash)
  class_name = obj['json_class'].split('::').inject(Kernel) { |namespace, const_name| namespace.const_get(const_name) }
  args = obj['data']
  word = class_name.new(*args)
else
  word = obj
end
```